# Override an Override?

Tags: java, android

I have an Activity in a Library  that has a menu in it.  The menu has all the standard attributes as well as the @Override on onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected.

In my actual project which imports above library I have another activity that extends teh above activity.   For this specific implementation of this program I want to have a different menu on this activity so inside this activities code base add add onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected with the proper @Override, but i get the menu from the Library, not the override in the library.

What could I be doing wrong?

**Base Class:**

```
public class ListItems extends ListActivity {
    public static final int LOGOUT  = 0;
    public static final int HISTORY  = 1;
    public static final int REFRESH  = 2;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add(0, LOGOUT ,0,"Log Out");
    menu.add(0,HISTORY,0,"Order History");
    menu.add(0,REFRESH,0,"SMS");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(com.imobileminutes.library.R.id.text);
    switch (item.getItemId()){
       case LOGOUT:
            Intent logOut = new Intent(ListItems.this,MainScreen.class);
            startActivity(logOut);
            finish();
            return true;
        case HISTORY:
            Intent orderHistory = new Intent(this,OrderItems.class);
            startActivity(orderHistory);
            return true;
        case REFRESH:
            Intent orderHistory = new Intent(this,OrderItems.class);
            startActivity(orderHistory);
            return true;
}
    return false;
}
}
```

**Override Class**

```
public class ListItems extends com.imobileminutes.library.ListItems {
    static final int SMS = 2;


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    Log.d("onCreateOptionsMenu", "My onCreateOptionsMenu ran");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HEllo Menu Created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    Log.d("onCreateOptionsMenu", "My onOptionsItemSelected ran");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HElloonOptionsItemSelected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    return false;
}
```

}

**CONCLUSION**
It ended up being that my library was calling ListItems.this and CreateAccount.this which was referencing the activities in the library not in the extended classes.

I added an intent for every extended activity type and nwo call that, thus bringing up the extended activity rather than the base activity.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Make sure the parameters for your override match the original method. Could you possibly provide code?

Comment: How can we know if you don't show us your code?

Comment: On the first iteration is an exact copy of those two methods, changing only the Wording on the menu to ensure it works.

Comment: Still need to see more code and how you are invoking it.

Comment: Its a menu, I'm pressing the menu button

Answer (score 1):

Either you didn't copy and paste the code correctly, or part of the problem is in your **base** class, which provides the same definition for `onCreateOptionsMenu` as your derived class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add(0, LOGOUT ,0,"Log Out");
    menu.add(0,HISTORY,0,"Order History");
    menu.add(0,REFRESH,0,"SMS");
    return true;
}
```

That last line can't be right -- I'm pretty sure the last line of the base class implementation should be: `menu.add(0,REFRESH,0,"REFRESH");`.

But that last line of `onCreateOptionsMenu` also needs to be changed in the derived class:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add(0, LOGOUT ,0,"Log Out");
    menu.add(0, HISTORY,0,"Order History");
    menu.add(0, SMS,0,"SMS"); // Use the correct constant (SMS instead of REFRESH)
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**: Also, you can simplify the code a bit, by re-using the superclass implementation for those choices where you're currently just copying the superclass code (LOGOUT and HISTORY):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(com.imobileminutes.library.R.id.text);
    // Left this as a 'switch'; you might want to use an 'if' instead.
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case SMS:
        AppClass.sendSMS("8135551212", "Hello Jason");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: yes I didn't copy it for this example correctly, I have fixed it

Comment: @Jason Carter: Well, you've still got what looks like a transcription error in the base class definition of `onCreateOptionsMenu` -- see the last line.

Comment: @Jason Carter: For that matter, the last two cases of the switch in `onOptionsItemSelected` are implemented identically. As you've probably discovered by now, it's **much** better to do a direct copy-and-paste than to try retyping the code: the more accurate the code you provide, the more accurate the answers will be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fully qualified name on the import my suspicion is you are referencing the wrong class.

Comment: if I take out everything in the overriden class, leaving just empty brackets, it works fine per the Base class, so the reference is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the way I was calling the Activitys.  I was calling the Activity directly in the Library rather than calling the overridden one.   Since the overriden ones will be dynamic depending on the Apps naming, I ended up using Intents that will search for the callers packagename and append the specific intent onto it.

As soon as I set all that up, my SMS menu item showed.